# Polymer paper-dialog not hiding on button press

Tags: javascript, polymer, material-design

I have a paper-dialog set up and for some reason when the user presses either the affirmative or dismissive buttons the paper-dialog doesn't close.

My buttons are setup as follows, which seems to be correct:

```
<paper-button dismissive hover on-tap="{{addNewGraph}}">Cancel</paper-button>
<paper-button affirmative hover on-tap="{{addNewGraph}}">Submit</paper-button>
```

Here's a plunker that is very similar to what I am doing:
http://plnkr.co/edit/6aNT88vi9lHLwLN9Pab3?p=preview

Any thoughts on why this isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want yo use the affirmative and dismissive attributes you have to use paper-action-dialog. i am not sure why this got split into another element. but it happened a few versions ago.

```
<paper-action-dialog id="secondDialog" backdrop transition="paper-dialog-transition-center">
  <div layout horizontal>
    <paper-button raised class="colored" self-center>Upload File</paper-button>
    <paper-input-decorator label="Enter URL for Dataset" floatingLabel error="A URL is required!" flex self-center>
      <input is="core-input" id="graphSource" required>
    </paper-input-decorator>
  </div>
  <div>
    <paper-button dismissive hover on-tap="{{addNewGraph}}">Cancel</paper-button>
    <paper-button affirmative hover on-tap="{{addNewGraph}}">Submit</paper-button>
  </div>
</paper-action-dialog>
```

trying to work with your plunker i had a similar issue to what we talked about in another post having issue accessing elements inside the dialog. so i put everything in a custom element accept for the button to toggle the first dialog.

http://plnkr.co/edit/dWmkTeY17wEE3hXhQFql?p=preview

Comment: So I got distracted by another project but finally got back to this project and this was perfect thanks